# How can I tell whether an ember model is embedded?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models: Team and Players. On my backend all the player records are embedded in it's corresponding team record and I am using the EmbeddedRecordsMixin and the following code so that the front end can handle the embedded records:

```
App.TeamSerializer = App.ApplicationSerializer.extend( DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    players: { embedded: 'always' }
  },
});
```

There are times when I want to know whether a model is embedded for simple CRUD functionality, is there any programmatic way to determine whether an ember model is embedded in another model?

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm currently doing it is that when I create a model in ember and declare the belongsTo relationship I pass in a boolean as an option as follows:

```
# In my player model
team: DS.belongsTo('team', {isEmbedded: true})
```

And then when I want to check whether its embedded I loop through the relationships and see whether the isEmbedded option returns true like this:

```
player.eachRelationship(function(name, relationship) {
  if(relationship.options.isEmbedded) {
    // Do something
  }
});
```

I'm happy to hear from you if there is a more robust way of checking whether a model is embedded!